# I am trying to run the below mentioned code but getting an error

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package com.complete.reference;

public class shift {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            byte a = 64, b;
            int i;
            i = a << 2;
            b = (byte) (a << 2);
            System.out.println("Original value of a: " + a);
            System.out.println("i and b: " + i + " " + b);
      }
}
```

> Error: Main method not found in class com.complete.reference.shift, please define the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Nothing wroing with your code.Your source code is not compiled .Try fix the libraries problems in Java Build Path.

Comment: Copied your code to ideone (http://ideone.com/9spjxd) where it works without problems.

Comment: Make a habit of naming your `class name` using capital.

Comment: Move the brackets: String[] args. Then recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine try to write class name in capital letter otherwise it's okay,
The possible error can be the way how you have added your external jars, Try to fix the libraries problems in Java Build Path.